# Transpose single excel column to multiple rows based on report with python

Tags: python, excel, utf-8

Goal is something similar to this:

```
['name_1' , '1. name_1' , 'Cat' , 'Dog']
['name_2' , '2.name_2' , '....']
[...]
```

[Data](https://gist.github.com/SirChurchill9999/e9bafe5c016ad3f0f22cc3c155be217a/raw/1f2f31618c274703d2e0bc2c348e4659e7f3b1c8/sample123.txt):

```
name_1
1. name_1
Cat
Dog
Variable_1: Dog
name_2
2.name_2
Dog
Mole
name_3
3.name_3
Cat
Dog
Mole
```

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://gist.github.com/SirChurchill9999/e9bafe5c016ad3f0f22cc3c155be217a/raw/1f2f31618c274703d2e0bc2c348e4659e7f3b1c8/sample123.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            record = [next(f).decode().strip()]
            if record != 'Mole':
            #Goal is to omit 'Mole' from the final dataset
                record.append(next(f).decode().strip())
            print(record)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

I've tried various code similar to the above. I considered using a `range`, but that wouldn't work because there's no set # of lines per report (as seen in the data). Basically, I'm trying to have the program skip over any lines that contain certain text, like `Dog`, `Cat`, or `Mole`.

When I run the above code, it gets somewhat close to what I want, but I also get some random characters thrown in:

```
['name_1', '1. name_1']
['Cat\xa0AR', '\xa0Dog']
# In the real data, some of the lines include a colon, like Variable_1: Dog
# Note how 'Cat' and 'Dog' ended up on separate lines from 'name_1' and "1. name_1'. They 
should all occur in sequence in the same frame []

['name_2', '2.name_2']
['Dog\xa0AR', '.....']
```

*Side note*: the original data was exported to a tab delimited text (.txt) file. All the data was arranged in individual cells on the original .xlsx file (as see in the data above).

**UPDATE**: This is the latest result that I am getting:

```
['name_1', '1. name_1']
['Cat', 'Dog']
['name_2', '2.name_2']
['Dog', 'Mole']
['3.name_3', 'Cat']
['Dog', 'Mole']
```

Comment: Why the UTF8 tag? Both Python 3 and Excel use UTF8 for all text. UTF8 is the encoding of characters to bytes, not some kind of escape sequence. This page, like almost all web pages, is UTF8. All the characters in this comment are UTF8. If you want to type some non-US character ... just type it όπως κάνω τώρα. You don't need escape sequences or decoding

Comment: In any case I can't reproduce the problem. I get `['Cat', 'Dog']`. Are you using Python 2 perhaps? `decode()` isn't needed either

Comment: Finally, what you posted isn't an Excel file, it's just a text file with one value per line. There are no separators or tabs. An Excel file is a ZIP package containing XML files. You can read it using libraries like openpyxl

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just ran the code and got: `['name_1', '1. name_1']
['Cat', 'Dog']
['name_2', '2.name_2']
['Dog', 'Mole']
['3.name_3', 'Cat']
['Dog', 'Mole']` I'm aiming to have them in the correct report each, like this: `['name_1', '1. name_1', 'Cat', 'Dog']`

Comment: I repeat - this isn't an Excel file and doesn't even have columns. There's only one value per line. The only reason you got two values is that you called `next` two times and appended the results to `record`. If you call it 4 times you'll get 4 values. Reading an Excel file is a *lot* easier than this.

Comment: y "Variable_1: Dog" is ommited too?